# How to properly set is_training when using iterators in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I have a `is_training` variable which I still have to define in my `main.py` file like this:

```
is_training = tf.placeholder(tf.bool, name='is_training')
```

Then I call my `inference` method from another file like this (x is input):

```
test = net.inference(x, is_training)
```

Finally, in my session I do this:

```
sess.run(test, feed_dict={x: test_x, is_training: True})
```

However, I would like to place `is_training` inside my inference function. Is that possible somehow?

Comment: Why don't you put it inside a `net` and create a getter?

Comment: Hmm, that is not the nicest way either is it? Not sure if it even works. Problem is when inference is called at the beginning when there is no session yet. I would like to get the value of `is_training` in inference and work with it, however, that is not possible @Maxim

Comment: You don't need the value, you need the placeholder itself. It's needed in 3 places: inference model, training model and session run

Comment: Well yes, that is exactly the problem. At the moment I need it in three places, however, actually, I only need it in the inference() method, and feed it in the session which is fine, but It would be cool if  I wouldn't have to pass it to the inference method, but that is just not possible I guess, unless I write a getter which is even more code :D  @Maxim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need `is_training` only in inference, I'd suggest you [`tf.placeholder_with_default`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/placeholder_with_default). This way you can define it only in `net.inference()` method and **not** pass in session:

```py
self.is_training = tf.placeholder_with_default(False, shape=(),name='is_training')
```

When you have to change it to `True`, you can simply do:

```py
sess.run(test, feed_dict={x: test_x, net.is_training: True})
```

Note that tensorflow doesn't care about the scope of python variable or field. Once the placeholder is defined, it's in the graph.